# Reactjs/Javascript update object dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `object`:

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({});
```

And in `useEffect` it will update `form`:

```
let obj = {
  id:1,
  info: {information: 1, task: 2, other: 3}
}

setForm(obj)
```

And I want to update this object values by this function `handleForm`:

```
const handleForm = (name, value, type, object) => {
  if(object){
      setForm({...form, [object]: {[name]: value}})
  } else {
      setForm({...form, [name]: value});
  }
}
```

Here is for example I update a key's value:

```
<Input value={obj.info.information} onChange={(e)=>handleForm('information', e.target.value, false, 'info')}/>
```

By this, I want to update `info` object, `information` key's value. It works and updates `information` but it going to remove other keys like `task` and `other`, actually it replaces not updating the whole object. I use `...form` prevState but wondering how can I keeps prev keys on update. should I use something like `...object` ?

**[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-morse-qqfjzm)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handleForm when condition for object is hit, you replace the whole object with a single value. Instead, you want to spread existing values and add the new one to it, like so:

```
      setForm({ ...form, [object]: { ...form[object], [name]: value } });
```